# why does the show variable here trigger only on the last element of the array?

Tags: javascript

I have a date input on my page, here I have an array with values that is basically the number of days that I want in a month.

```
dateNumber = [23, 25];
show = true;

if(service == "7305"){
    for(let i = 0; i < dateNumber.length ; i++) {
        if (date.getDate() == dateNumber[i]) {
            show = true;
        } else {
            show = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Now it looks like this:

[image: dateinput].

The problem is that show is true for 23 and for 25, but it shows only the last element. How can I fix it ?

Comment: You need to break the loop as soon as the `if` condition evaluates to true. Initialize `show` with `false` and inside the loop, remove the the `else` block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that if the date is 23, it will be set to `true` initially, but the second time through the loop it is not equal to 25, so you will set it to `false` again!

To fix this simply break out of the loop, or even better, just use:

`show = [23, 25].includes(date.getDate());`

Answer (score 1):

There are some problems with your code.

I would recommend using the strict mode. `'use strict';` which eliminates some JavaScript silent errors by changing them to throw errors.

Read more about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode

Currently, you have your defined your variables like so.

```
dateNumber = [23, 25];
show = true;
```

Although it works but these are leaked globals. When you declare variables without `var`, `let`, or `const`. JS creates that variable in the global scope.

You should always use `var`, `let`, or `const` to define your variables.
Read more about it here: https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/var-let-and-const-whats-the-difference/

Also use the strict equality operator instead of `==`

Read more about it here: [Which equals operator (== vs ===) should be used in JavaScript comparisons?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/359494/which-equals-operator-vs-should-be-used-in-javascript-comparisons)

Try this:

```
'use strict';
const date = new Date();
const dateNumber = [23, 25];
let show = false;

if (service === '7305') {
  for (let i = 0; i < dateNumber.length; i++) {
    if (date.getDate() === dateNumber[i]) {
      show = true;
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: This is a better answer than mine. I upvote this.

Answer (score 0):

You need at least two elements, or have a logo.

```
dateNumber = [23, 25];
show1 = true;
show2 = true;
```

then:

```
if (date.getDate() == dateNumber[i]) {
     show1 = true;
     show2 = true;
 } else {
     show1 = false;
     show2 = false;
 }
```

Comment: "or have a logo" ??